# Assitance with query syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following syntax error with my query. Can anyone help me out?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN p_property ON p_session.PropertyID=p_property.PropertyID,LEFT JOIN p_r' at line 1

```
SELECT p_property.PropertyName,p_property.DistrictID,
        p_property.SettlementID,
        AVG (p_reviews.ReviewScore) AS avg_score, 
        COUNT (p_facilities.FacilitiesID) AS num_facilities 
FROM p_session, 
LEFT JOIN p_property ON p_session.PropertyID=p_property.PropertyID,
LEFT JOIN p_reviews ON p_reviews.PropertyID=p_session.PropertyID, 
LEFT JOIN p_facilities ON p_facilities.PropertyID=p_session.PropertyID;
```

Comment: Can I suggest you read the [Mysql Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to see the JOIN Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Extra Comma

```
FROM p_session,
```

Should be

```
FROM p_session
```

Comment: And the other comma's also need removing between  the joins

Comment: Indeed. I was not offering to play compiler. Just answer the one question generating the error message. This question will be deleted soon, I imagine.

Comment: @RiggsFolly as does that apostrophe

Comment: @Strawberry `Nobody expects the apostrophe inquisition`